# skip and limit in mongodb returning one less document than its supposed to

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection called orders and i am running the following query on it

```
module.exports.readPendingOrders = function(count){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Order.find({status: "pending"})
        .sort({created: -1})
        .limit(100)
        .skip(count)
        .exec()
        .then(rem => {
            resolve(rem);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            reject(error.message)
        })
})
}
```

I have this same paginated format trying to get all documents and to get all documents with status : "completed".

The problem is that it always returns one less document than i am expecting. 
It always skips the last record in the database, and i have about 8 records in the database.

The front end is a react app and i didnt notice it there till i was testing the query in Postman and i saw that it returned one less document than i expected.

Not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: Is that limit value 100 hardcoded or are you showing us a sample ? Usually ".sort().limit(skipCount+limitCount).skip(limitCount)" & skipCount can be calculated by ((pageNum - 1)*limitCount)..

Comment: Define "one less document than expected". How many documents do you have? What is the value of `count` where you're seeing the unexpected behavior? Is this a missing document for every page or are you missing only one document out of the entire collection? If it's out of the entire collection, are you possibly missing the newest document only? Are you correctly calculating the page sizes and number of pages? There are quite a few unknowns here and we can't really help you with only the information you've provided so far.

Comment: Its skipping the newest document in the collection. Its not skipping the newest document if the result of the query is one document, if its 2 or more it skips the newest document

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't appear to be incorrect. It sounds to me like your issue is further up the call stack. I suspect that you have an error somewhere in your pagination logic where you're performing an incorrect calculation for the `count` value. Without seeing that code, it's not possible to help you any more than this.